# Измерение скорости работы кода python

Tags: python, pyqt5, tkinter

Я хочу внутри кода, прописать код, который будет создавать окно вывода времени затраченного на запуск окна или выполнения программы, без учёта времени потраченного на создания окна для вывода:

для примера возьмём окно созданное библиотекой `pyqt5` которое мы будем проверять и саму программу которая создает окно созданное библиотекой `tkinter` для вывода. Если я программу для вывода запущу в отдельном файле то она будет работать как надо, а если я хочу поместить её внутри самой программы которую я хочу проверить то она не работает.

Я попробовал код вывода отделить от программы для проверки каким-то разделителем (от `#/*` до `#*/`)в виде комментария и при чтении файла пропускать код помещенный в отделитель.

Код вывода:

```
from tkinter import *
import timeit

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')

with open('test.py', 'r') as f:
    code = f.read()

time = timeit.timeit(code, number = 1)
text = '[Program finished in %d %s]' %\
(time * 1000, 'ms') if time < 1 else (time, 's') if 1 < time < 60\
else (time / 60, 'm') if 60 < time < 3600 else (time / 3600, 'h')

Label(text = text).place(x = 10, y = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

Код который я проверяю уже с кодом вывода:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(450, 450)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

#/* < --- начало
from tkinter import *
import timeit

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')

with open('test.py', 'r') as f:
    code = f.read()
    code = code.replace(code[code.find('#/*') : code.find('#*/') + 3], '') # < --- то что я попробовал сделать 

time = timeit.timeit(code, number = 1)
text = '[Program finished in %d %s]' %\
(time * 1000, 'ms') if time < 1 else (time, 's') if 1 < time < 60\
else (time / 60, 'm') if 60 < time < 3600 else (time / 3600, 'h')

Label(text = text).place(x = 10, y = 10)

root.mainloop()
#*/ < --- конец код вывода помесчёный в код который проверяем 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

То как это должно быть по идее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу здесь кучу проблем.

1. Строка поиска маркеров должна выглядеть, например, так:

```
    code = code.replace(code[code.find('#''/''*') : code.find('#''*''/')], '') # < --- то что я попробовал сделать
```

В ней нельзя использовать маркеры выглядящие абсолютно так же как и настоящие маркеры. Иначе она будет находить их в самой себе, а не там, где вы их указали.

2. Условие `if __name__ == "__main__":` будет препятствовать исполнению коде под ним из-под `timeit`. Там `__name__` равен `"timeit"`.
3. Команда `sys.exit(...)` завершит программу полностью. Так что окно со временем никогда не выведется.
4. Ну и код ниже надо взять в скобочки. Иначе `else` будет относиться не к вариантам подстановки, а к содержимому строки. И для времени больше секунды подстановка в форматирование выполняться не будет.

```
(time * 1000, 'ms') if time < 1 else (time, 's') if 1 < time < 60\
else (time / 60, 'm') if 60 < time < 3600 else (time / 3600, 'h')
```

*Ну и вообще, мне не понятен смысл всей этой задумки.*

Comment: Я сделал то что вы посоветовали это сработало. Теперь создается два окна код при чтении пропускает всё что было помещено в комментарий и выводит время от мили секунд до часу, но возникла следующая проблема время всегда выводиться 0. Код https://gitlab.com/strtz57/test/-/blob/main/test.py